# How to get selected dropdown value in Node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, drop-down-menu

With a handlebar home.handlebars that has this dropdown menu for gender as part of the registration form...

```
<form id="register-modal" class="ui modal form" method="post" action="/register">
  <div class="field">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
  <div class="two fields">
    <div class="field">
      <label>Age</label>
      <input type="text" name="age">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Gender</label>
      <select class="ui fluid dropdown">
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
        <option value="non-binary">Non-binary</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 <div class="field">
    <label>Email Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <center><button class="ui button" type="submit">Submit</button></center>
</form>
```

I have a function that creates a new user object like this...

```
function user(name, pass) {
   return {
      name: name,
      pass: pass
   };
}
```

Here is how I'm retrieving the information from the form. This is `routes.js`:

```
router.post('/register', (req,res) => {
var name = req.body.username;
var pass = req.body.password;
var email = req.body.email;

if (!name || !pass || !email ) {
  res.redirect('registration?code=fail');
} else{
db.insertUser(creations.user(name,pass,email,false),(user) => {
  if(user){
    db.login(user,(sessionID)=>{
      res.cookie('sessionID', sessionID);
      res.redirect('/feed');
    })
  } else res.redirect('registration?code=IU');
})
}})
```

Comment: How do you retrieve the values from form ?

Comment: I've made edits and added the code that retrieves the values from the form @RayonDabre.

Comment: NO, You have added backend script..How do you retrieve values from the form ? Clientside ?

Comment: I'm new to Node. I'm not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: How do you access these `return {
      name: name,
      pass: pass,
      gender: gender
   };` values ?

Comment: I have a database.js file that connects to a database in mongdb. Inside database.js, I define a function called insertUser that inserts a new user into the database.

Comment: Bro, How do you send values to the NodeJs ?

Comment: I thought that's what route.js was doing. What would a request for sending data from a form to the server would like?

Comment: How do you invoke `user` function ? What arguments do you pass ?

Comment: I've added some other files that calls the `user` function in the post

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. To grab the selected value from the dropdown, I just call:

```
var gender = req.body.gender
```